# launch icon for COMMAND LINE in Win 8.1

Tags: command-line, launcher

How can I create the launching icon of COMMAND LINE TERMINAL under Windows 8.1 ?
I have already one but I do not remember how have I created it.

**EDIT**
I mean the icon at the left bottom and launched as displayed:

[image]

Comment: you mean command prompt?

Comment: @Moab I'm not an expert on WIndows but I have made an Edit to my Question. I think I do mean `command prompt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like a shortcut to **Command Prompt** you can follow these steps:

- Right-Click the desktop and click the **New** Option
- Then click on **Shortcut** in the sub-menu.
- The **Create Shortcut** dialog appears. In the box under `Type the location of this item:` type `cmd`. Then press the next button.
- You can then type a name for the shortcut, such as `Command Prompt`, and then press the finish button.

Verify the shortcut was created successfully by double-clicking the new icon on your desktop.

Comment: That's great: it does what I supposed it would.